# Trigger different order eMail notification with hooks for orders made by prepayment (bacs) or invoices (cheque)

Tags: php, email, woocommerce, triggers, hook

I would like to use **two different eMail notifications** for customers in WooCommerce. One notification should be, if someone order with the **prepayment method**, which is called bacs in WooCommerce. The other notification should be, if someone order with the **invoice payment**. The invoice payment is not native in WooCommerce, so I would like to use the cheque payment gateway for the invoice orders.

To achieve this I tried to change a custom plugin for WooCommerce so that it adds custom email notifications for "Prepayment" and "Invoice" orders. The main structure for this plugin comes from https://www.ibenic.com/create-custom-woocommerce-email

Here is an overview of my plugin's folder structure:

```
Main Folder: custom-wc-email
    File: custom-wc-email.php
    Subfolder: emails
        File: class-wc-custom-invoice-email.php
        File: class-wc-custom-prepayment-email.php
    Subfolder: templates
        Subfolder: emails
            File: wc-custom-invoice-email.php
            File: wc-custom-prepayment-email.php
        Subfolder: plain
            File: wc-custom-invoice-email.php
            File: wc-custom-prepayment-email.php
```

If I use the plugin with the two hooks given by default:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_cancelled_notification', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_cancelled_notification', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );
```

The plugin sends successfully the email Template given in `/custom-wc-email/templates/emails`
**But I would like to sent the eMail notification when an order is made by prepayment or invoice payment.**

So I tried to replace the default hooks with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_bacs', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_blocks_payment_method_type_registration', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ), 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );
```

The idea for this hooks came from https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/payment-complete-hooks.html
I tested the hooks one by another, but none of them sends the eMail given in `/custom-wc-email/templates/emails`, instead the default WooCommerce notification mail is being send.

Then I tried to use the hooks in `class-wc-custom-prepayment-email.php`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ), 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ), 20 );
```

With that hooks, an eMail different than the default WooCommerce notification is being sent. But its still a mixture of the content in `/custom-wc-email/templates/emails` and the default WooCommerce order notification eMail.

The code in `class-wc-custom-prepayment-email.php` is:

```
    <?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Email' ) ) {
    return;
}

/**
 * Class WC_Custom_Prepayment_Email
 */
class WC_Custom_Prepayment_Email extends WC_Email {

    /**
     * Create an instance of the class.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->id                 = 'wc_custom_prepayment_email';
        $this->customer_email     = true;
        $this->title              = __( 'Prepayment Order to Customer', 'custom-wc-email' );
        $this->description        = __( 'An email sent to the customer when an order is set to prepayment.', 'custom-wc-email' );
        $this->heading            = __( 'Prepayment Order', 'custom-wc-email' );
        $this->subject            = __( 'Prepayment Order - {order_number}', 'custom-wc-email' );
        $this->template_html      = 'emails/wc-custom-prepayment-email.php';
        $this->template_plain     = 'emails/plain/wc-custom-prepayment-email.php';
        $this->template_base      = CUSTOM_WC_EMAIL_PATH . 'templates/';

        //add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_bacs', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );
        //add_action( 'woocommerce_blocks_payment_method_type_registration', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ), 20 );
        //add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ), 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ), 20 );




        /** Diese beiden Hooks versenden die Email bei stornierung der Bestellung. Das Senden funktioniert **/
        //add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_cancelled_notification', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );
        //add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_cancelled_notification', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Trigger Function that will send this email to the customer.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     *
     */



    function send_prepayment_email( $order_id ) {
        $this->object = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        if ( version_compare( '3.0.0', WC()->version, '>' ) ) {
            $order_email = $this->object->billing_email;
        } else {
            $order_email = $this->object->get_billing_email();
        }

        $this->recipient = $order_email;


        if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
    }

    /**
     * Get content html.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_html() {
        return wc_get_template_html( $this->template_html, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
            'sent_to_admin' => false,
            'plain_text'    => false,
            'email'         => $this
        ), '', $this->template_base );
    }

    /**
     * Get content plain.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_plain() {
        return wc_get_template_html( $this->template_plain, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
            'sent_to_admin' => false,
            'plain_text'    => true,
            'email'         => $this
        ), '', $this->template_base );
    }

}
```

And the code for `class-wc-custom-invoice-email.php` is:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Email' ) ) {
    return;
}

/**
 * Class WC_Custom_Invoice_Email
 */
class WC_Custom_Invoice_Email extends WC_Email {

    /**
     * Create an instance of the class.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->id                 = 'wc_custom_invoice_email';
        $this->customer_email     = true;
        $this->title              = __( 'Invoice Order to Customer', 'custom-wc-email' );
        $this->description        = __( 'An email sent to the customer when an order is invoiced.', 'custom-wc-email' );
        $this->heading            = __( 'Invoice Order', 'custom-wc-email' );
        $this->subject            = __( 'Invoice Order - {order_number}', 'custom-wc-email' );
        $this->template_html      = 'emails/wc-custom-invoice-email.php';
        $this->template_plain     = 'emails/plain/wc-custom-invoice-email.php';
        $this->template_base      = CUSTOM_WC_EMAIL_PATH . 'templates/';

        //add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_invoice_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', array( $this, 'send_invoice_email' ), 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $this, 'send_invoice_email' ), 20 );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Trigger Function that will send this email to the customer.
     *
     * @param int $order_id Order ID
     * @return void
     */
    public function send_invoice_email( $order_id ) {
        $this->object     = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $this->recipient  = $this->object->get_billing_email();
        $this->placeholders['{order_number}'] = $this->object->get_order_number();

        if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers() );
    }

    /**
     * Get content html.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_html() {
        return wc_get_template_html( $this->template_html, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
            'sent_to_admin' => false,
            'plain_text'    => false,
            'email'         => $this,
        ), '', $this->template_base );
    }

    /**
     * Get content plain.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_plain() {
        return wc_get_template_html( $this->template_plain, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
            'sent_to_admin' => false,
            'plain_text'    => true,
            'email'         => $this,
        ), '', $this->template_base );
    }
}
```

But in `class-wc-custom-invoice-email.php` for the invoice order notifications the hooks:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', array( $this, 'send_invoice_email' ), 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $this, 'send_invoice_email' ), 20 );
```

give an internal server error, after sending an order with the invoice payment method.
I'm not sure if these hooks are the right ones to **trigger the email sending** depending on an order made by **prepayment (bacs)** or an order by **invoice (where I am using the cheque gateway for)**.

Does anyone have an idea here why the hooks:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_bacs', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_blocks_payment_method_type_registration', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ), 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', array( $this, 'send_prepayment_email' ) );
```

doesn't trigger the bacs or cheque payment?

You can find the files in GitHub [GitHub custom mail woocommerce](https://github.com/bosselmann/custom_email_trigger_woocommerce/tree/main)

Comment: Can you add your complete plugin in GitHub (even temporarily) and provide the link please.

Comment: Shure I will try that. I hope the links works: 
https://github.com/bosselmann/custom_email_trigger_woocommerce/tree/main/custom-wc-email

Comment: Link works, but this is the correct link to be able to upload it: [GitHub main path link](https://github.com/bosselmann/custom_email_trigger_woocommerce/tree/main)